# Can't set Homebrew python to bet the default python?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, homebrew

I just wiped my Mac and reinstalled macOS.

I installed Homebrew and then installed Python with `brew install python`. But now if I use `which python` I get `/usr/bin/python`. When typing `echo $PATH` it returns `usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

My .bash_profile file:

```
# Load the shell dotfiles, and then some:
# * ~/.path can be used to extend `$PATH`.
# * ~/.extra can be used for other settings you don’t want to commit.
for file in ~/.{path,bash_prompt,exports,aliases,functions,extra}; do
  [ -r "$file" ] && source "$file"
done
unset file

# Brew Cask install location
export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="appdir=~/Applications"
```

My .path file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

What do I need to do to set Homebrew Python to default?

//edit
I just installed ruby with Homebrew and it works but Python doesn't...

//edit2 [some adjustments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KBKt.png)

Comment: There's a typo somewhere: `usr/local/bin` in your claimed output is not the same as `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: In which file could it be? I can't find one in .bash_profile and .path...

Comment: The paths don't seem to quite match up, if you're just getting started with homebrew, one thing that is going to make your life simpler is using a local, non-privileged prefix.

Comment: @VenatorScientiae It might simply be in your question; maybe `echo $PATH` really does return `/usr/local/bin/...` instead of `usr/local/bin:...`. We can't tell, though, which is the case.

Comment: What is the output of `which -a python`?

Comment: @chepner /usr/bin/python

Comment: no one with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your `$PATH`, check the output of homebrew when installing Python `brew install python`:

```
==> Caveats
This formula installs a python2 executable to /usr/local/bin.
If you wish to have this formula's python executable in your PATH then add
the following to ~/.zshrc:
  export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"

Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip2 install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip2 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: http://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html
```

Something like this should work:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$HOME/Library/Python/3.6/bin:..."
```